# Call php file in local host from Matlab?

Tags: php, matlab, localhost

I have a .php file that returns information correctly when called by typing localhost/lolo/readInfo.php in my browser. When I try opening this url in Matlab with webread() or urlread() I get the following message:

The '' protocol specified in URL, 'localhost/lolo/readInfo.php', is
not supported. Specify the URL with the protocol 'http://' or
'https://'.

Which other function could I use to get the information using Matlab?
Wampserver is running and the .php file uses the functions curl_init, curl_setopt, curl_exec